# Police officials/personnel/people

Tags: word-request

> Outside the bank, the Chief of police and some other police officials/personnel/people were conferring.

What would you call it if we don't talk normal police officers but someone of a higher rank?

Comment: Ranks vary from country to country, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_ranks_of_the_United_States)'s a police-rank model of the States.

Comment: "High-ranking [police] officers"?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably describe them simply as “**senior** police officials”. “High ranking” would also be an acceptable term to use.

Comment: Yes, senior is the way to go. But I am not sure about high-ranking in this context.